# Got error Alamofire.AFError.ServerTrustFailureReason.noRequiredEvaluator when using DisabledTrustEvaluator

Tags: swift, ssl-certificate, alamofire, rxalamofire

I've got a class `AuthenticationApiClient` that has this integration test:

```
func testCheckPhoneNumber_WithExistingPhoneNumber_ShouldReturnRegisteredStatus() throws {
    let sessionFactory: () -> Session = {
        let serverTrustManager = ServerTrustManager(evaluators: ["xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8443" : DisabledTrustEvaluator()])
        let session = Session(serverTrustManager: serverTrustManager)
        return session
    }
    let hostFactory: () -> String = {
        return "https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8443/staging/"
    }
    let sut = AuthenticationApiClient(sessionFactory: sessionFactory, 
                                      hostFactory: hostFactory)
    let expectSuccess = expectation(description: "Should return phone number data from API")
    let params = PhoneRegistrationRequestModel(vendorId: "xxxxxxxxxx",
                                               phoneNumber: "xxxxxxxxxx",
                                               idFA: "xxxxxxxxxxx")
    sut.checkPhoneNumber(params)
        .subscribe(onNext: { responseModel in
            expectSuccess.fulfill()
            XCTAssertEqual(false, responseModel.rdl)
            XCTAssertEqual("00", responseModel.registrantStatus)
        }, onError: { error in
            XCTFail("Returned error: \(error)")
        })
        .disposed(by: disposeBag)
    wait(for: [expectSuccess], timeout: 5)
}
```

This is for staging environment where I don't need any SSL evaluation. That's why I used the `DisabledTrustEvaluator` But when I run this, I've got this error:

> serverTrustEvaluationFailed(reason: Alamofire.AFError.ServerTrustFailureReason.noRequiredEvaluator(host: "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"))

But when I used `Session.default`, it throws this:

> sessionTaskFailed(error: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1202 "The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be “xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx” which could put your confidential information at risk." UserInfo={NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Would you like to connect to the server anyway?, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3, NSErrorPeerCertificateChainKey=(.....

The code for AuthenticationApiClient is like this:

```
protocol AuthenticationApiClient {
    func checkPhoneNumber(_ params: PhoneRegistrationRequestModel) -> Observable<PhoneRegistrationResponseModel>
}

final class AuthenticationApi: AuthenticationApiClient {
    private let session: Session
    private let host: String
    init(sessionFactory: @escaping () -> Session,
         hostFactory: @escaping () -> String) {
        session = sessionFactory()
        host = hostFactory()
    }
    func checkPhoneNumber(_ params: PhoneRegistrationParam) -> Observable<PhoneRegistrationResponseModel> {
        let endpoint = "getRegistrantIdByPhone"
        guard let url = URL(string: host+endpoint) else { return .empty() }
        let httpHeaders: HTTPHeaders = HTTPHeadersMapper.map(from: ApiHeaders.default)

        return session.rx
            .data(.post, url,
                  parameters: params.toStringDictionary(), 
                  encoding: JSONEncoding.default,
                  headers: httpHeaders)
            .map { PhoneRegistrationResponseModelMapper.map($0) }
    }
}
```

What did I do wrong here? Can anybody help me? Thanks.

PS: Forgot to say that I'm using Swift 5, Alamofire 5.5.0 and RxAlamofire 6.1.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default all `ServerTrustManager`s require every host they see to match at least one evaluator. If you don't want that behavior you can you disable it when you create the `ServerTrustManager` instance: `ServerTrustManager(allHostsMustBeEvaluated: false, evaluators: ...)`.